# How to build a live data based on lateinit property?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, coroutine, deferred

I have a property with late initialization.
Now I want to provide a live data which does not emit anything until the property is initialized completely.
How to do this in proper Kotlin way?

```kotlin
class SomeConnection {
 val data: Flow<SomeData>
...

class MyViewModel {

 private lateinit var _connection: SomeConnection
 // private val _connection: CompletableDeferred<SomeConnection>()

 val data = _coonection.ensureInitilized().data.toLiveData()

 fun connect(){
  viewModelScope.launch {
   val conn = establishConnection()
   // Here I have to do something for the call ensureInitilized to proceed
  }
 }

 private suspend fun establishConnection(){
  ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare a MutableLiveData emitting values of type SomeConnection and a corresponding LiveData.

```
private val _connectionLiveData = MutableLiveData<SomeConnection>()
val connectionLiveData: LiveData<SomeConnection> = _connectionLiveData
```

Then assign value to `_connectionLiveData` when `_connection` is initialized:

```
if (::_connection.isInitialized()) _connectionLiveData.value = _connection
```

(or `_connectionLiveData.postValue(_connection)` if your code works concurrently)

Now observe this LiveData in another place in code, I'll use fragment here for the sake of example:

```
override fun firstOnViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    viewModel.connectionLiveData.observe(this, ::sendData)
}
```

Then send the desired data via the corresponding view model method